# Closing a system default launcher

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I've been developing an app which is a system launcher. It is a kiosk app to be more specific. I want it to have an exit button but problem is after exiting, it reopens the app.
I've tried many things; I tried killing the process and its background process too, but that didn't work. I tried starting an intent to the phone default launcher but the intent returns null.

So any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your purpose about killing the System Launcher but It's not a good solution to finish an app in Android especially System Launcher. You should handle the workflow in your code after exit action, like hiding buttons, etc.

Comment: My guess is he wants to have the kiosk launcher to be a temporary launcher for what I guess to be kiosk mode. Like kids mode that some devices have.